# Need more reputation to comment on a locked question

Tags: bug, comments, privileges, locked

When I click on the message saying a post is locked, the 50 reputation required pop-up comes up as if it wasn't locked:

> [image: Pop-up on locked post]

This would probably confuse new users as it is basically contradicting the locked post message.

I have found another locked question on Ask Different ([What was the very first Apple product?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/715/what-was-the-very-first-apple-product)) but the reputation thing does not pop-up when I have 50+ reputation there, so we can rule out the possibility of it just not checking for anything (ex. over 50 reputation) so it displays all the time.